# How to add meta tag in Next JS metadata

Tags: ios, next.js, metadata, meta-tags

I am trying to add a meta tag in Next JS 13.4, but I cannot. I have read the documentation and googled it but I couldn't find the solution. I am trying to add this HTML meta tag in the Next JS way.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="AppTitle">
```

What I am trying in Next JS metadata is

```
export const metadata = {
  title: 'MessageMoment - The real meaning to personal!',
  description: 'MessageMoment - The real meaning to personal!',
  creator: 'Chandan Sayed',
  short_name: 'MessageMoment',
  applicationName: 'MessageMoment',
  siteName: 'MessageMoment',
  appleMobileWebAppTitle: 'MessageMoment'
}
```

But it does not work, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `appleWebApp` property on metadata.

```
appleWebApp: {
         title: "app__title",
       }
```

If you use TypeScript then add the next.js `Metadata` interface. It will help you catch errors while writing.

Comment: May I ask you where can I get more information about using Metatag for Next JS?

Comment: Sure, you can find it here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata

Or, you can look up the next.js `Metadata` interface for which properties accept which type of values.

Comment: I looked there but was unable to find it. Anyway, thanks a lot!